# Mercurial not allowing commit for a folder that was previously removed and now needs to be added

Tags: mercurial

In a previous commit we had say folder EXAMPLE1 in the Mercurial repo and had to be deleted due to project configuration issues.

The project has been reorganized and a folder with the same name (EXAMPLE1) needs to be added again.

Mercurial is currently not allowing commit for that specific folder. No errors are shown. However, when commit is attempted, it shows as if nothing has been changed inside the folder.

Would appreciate it if you could please tell me how can the folder labeled as EXAMPLE1 can be added back to the mercurial repo.

Comment: HG doesn't add folders, it only adds files (IIRC). Are you adding specific files inside EXAMPLE1 and finding that HG is not responding to that?

Comment: Please add the output of `hg status`, so we can see more details about what is going on.

Comment: As @StayOnTarget commented `hg` does not track directories. Therefore, if you want it to create a directory that is otherwise empty, you need to [track a placeholder file](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/release4/lst/nulfile) in that directory. (You can name this file as you wish.)